# Using bycryptJS with sequelize

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to hash the user input password, but not sure if I should do this directly in the route that handles the post request to the database or in the actual model itself. I am using the bcrypt code from the documentation, and it seems like I need to pass in the function to the following code:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("B4c0/\/", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB. 
    });
});
```

I currently have this set up in my router file.

```
router.post('/friend-book/register', function(req, res){

            db.users.create(req.body).then(function(data){
                console.log("register data", data);

                console.log("poop", data.id);
                req.session.user = {
                    id: data.id,
                    name: data.name,
                    username: data.username,
                    email: data.email,
                    description: data.description
                };

                bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                        // Store hash in your password DB. 
                    });
                });

                res.render("profile", req.session.user);

            });
});
```

My model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var users = sequelize.define('users', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I put the hashing function inside a beforeCreate hook like so.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: { type:DataTypes.STRING, validate: { isEmail: true}, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type:DataTypes.STRING, required: true}
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
    },
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: function(user, options) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8, (err, data) => {
              if (err) reject(err);
              user.password = data;
              resolve();
            })
          });
        }
      }
  });
  return User;
};
```

One thing, I use (and always would use) the bcrypt module instead of bcrypt-js as it is a C++ implementation of bcrypt and much quicker.

Comment: okay thank you so much, I will look into this, but do I need to call the beforeCreate function in the routes where this query is being called from or does beforeCreate automatically get called when the program does a sequelize create?

Comment: and since you are using a new Promise, dont you have to pass the data to the then() function and in here you would do user.password = data?

Comment: Its automatically called before a new user is created. You don't have to pass data if you don't want to you can simple say

Comment: User.create(req.body).then(() => res.json(user))